# L5.3 - Validator - Get DB record when 'unique' si triggered

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using `Validator` to validate the input:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'short'         => 'required',
    'name'          => 'required|unique:type_event,name'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // fails validation
}
```

When the `unique` check is fired, is there a way to receive the `id` or the record that already exists into the DB? Or I've to call the Model for example with:

```
$data = TypeEventModel::where('name', '=', $request->input('name'))->firstOrFail();
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you print the `$validator->errors()` output and paste it here?

Comment: The unique validator just performs a count query with the attributes provided so you would have to perform the extra query yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a custom validation rule. Add the following code to `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in `boot()` method:

```
Validator::extend('unique_with_id', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    // First we query for an entity in given table, where given field equals the request value
    $found = DB::table($parameters[0])
        ->where($parameters[1], $value)
        ->first();

    // then we add custom replacer so that it gives the user a verbose error

    $validator->addReplacer('unique_with_id', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) use ($found) {
        // replace :entity placeholder with singularized table name and :id with duplicate entity's id
        return str_replace([':entity', ':id'], [str_singular($parameters[0]), $found->id], $message);
    });

    // finally return wether the entity was not found (the value IS unique)
    return !$found;
});
```

Then add the following validation message to `resources/lang/en/validation.php`

```
'unique_with_id'=>'Same :entity exists with ID :id',
```

Finally you can use

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'short'         => 'required',
    'name'          => 'required|unique_with_id:type_event,name'
]);
```